# Can not insert unique document using gmongo in Grails

Tags: mongodb, grails

I using gmongo (for Grails) library to insert data into mongodb. I want to insert with unique element. 
I try create a Unique Index for MongoDB:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { "object_id": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

However, There are some duplicated elements when I try to insert many time one data through webservice at the same time. Maybe, I got 3-5 duplicated elements when I insert 500 documents

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the function **ensureIndex** and **update** method with **upsert** parameter( true ).

Syntax:

```
db.collection.update( <query>, <update>, <upsert>, <multi> )
```

Refer [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. Let's me check it